# ScalingFunctions produces a warning on ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, coordinate-transformation

Using `ScalingFunctions` in a `ListDensityPlot` produces a warning *"An unknown option name has been used."* Yet, the code still seems to work.

```
table = Table[Mod[x, y], {x, 30}, {y, 20}];
plots = {ListDensityPlot[table], 
  ListDensityPlot[table, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}]}
```

[image: ScalingFunctions on ListDensityPlot]

Documentation for `ScalingFunctions` only acknowledges it works for `ListPlot`, `BarChart`, `Histogram` and `"other plotting functions"`, making no explicit mention to `ListDensityPlot`. Yet, the code compiles and the effects are visible. Is this intentional behaviour? Is it even correct?

Comment: You mention version-11. I don't have 11.0, but there is no syntax coloring issue in M11.1, and there is in M10.3.1. What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @CarlWoll I have 11.0.1.0

Comment: It looks like the support was added in M9 or earlier, and only got documented in M11.1.

Comment: @CarlWoll Ah, I see it in the patch notes now for 11.1. A bit vague, but it explains it. If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes support for some features is introduced into Mathematica, but not documented for various reasons. [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) is an example of this. It was added in M9 (or perhaps earlier) for many plotting functions, but documentation of this support for some plotting functions was not added until M11.1 or so.